# AEM CQ5 passing SlingHttpServletRequest Object to a service

Tags: osgi, aem

I am trying to pass SlingRequest object from a component jsp to a osgi service as follows. But the service is not getting registered. (not sure why?)

```
<c:set var="inverterData" value='<%=sling.getService(InverterFactory.class).getOverview(slingRequest, resourceResolver)%>' scope="request" />
```

Question : Is it allowed to pass a SlingRequest object from a component jsp to a osgi service ? If it is allowed, why my service not getting registered. If I take out SlingRequest object, the service is getting registered and I am able to call the service from jsp.

Answer (score 0):

including your OOTB `/libs/foundation/global.jsp` makes you to get the default tag libs, sling objects and CQ objects defined.

when you pass the fully qualified name of the service to `sling.getService` method, SlingRepository gets injected into service by the OSGi bundle managed component.

In your code snippet `sling.getService(InverterFactory.class)` the service is obtained from the **`sling`** SlingScriptHelper object to retrieve OSGi services available in Sling, and this generally will be called on the interface. After your creation of a Service object by using `sling.getService`, you can invoke any methods exposed by that service.

Have a look at the [ScriptHelper](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling8/org/apache/sling/scripting/core/ScriptHelper.htmll) api documentation and [sling scripting variables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SLING/Scripting+variables)

***try code snippet below***

`<% your.qualified.path.InverterFactory Invfac = sling.getService(your.qualified.path.InverterFactory.class); %>
<c:set var="inverterData" value='<%=Invfac.getOverview(slingRequest, resourceResolver)%>' scope="request" />`

also i don't think SlingRequest object should cause any problem, i have tried your code snippet syntax and just returned some string from OSGI service, it works fine. Below is my example

**HelloService Interface**

`public interface HelloService {
    public String getRepositoryName();
    public String getRepositoryName(SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest, ResourceResolver resourceResolver);
}`

**HelloServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@Component(metatype = false)
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {
 protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());    
    @Reference
    private SlingRepository repository;
    public String getRepositoryName() {
        return repository.getDescriptor(Repository.REP_NAME_DESC);
    }   
    public String getRepositoryName(SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest, ResourceResolver resourceResolver) {
    log.info("*** Inside my interface impl OSGI ***");
    String returnstr = repository.getDescriptor(Repository.REP_NAME_DESC)+" Data from OSGI";
       //return repository.getDescriptor(Repository.REP_NAME_DESC);
       return returnstr;
    }
}
```

**OSGICalling.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="com.mycompany.myrestservice.HelloService" %>
<%
com.mycompany.myrestservice.HelloService hs = sling.getService(com.mycompany.myrestservice.HelloService.class);
String repo = hs.getRepositoryName() ; 
out.println("myrepo::" + repo);
%>   
<c:set var="inverteraa" value='<%=sling.getService(com.mycompany.myrestservice.HelloService.class).getRepositoryName(slingRequest,resourceResolver)%>' />
<c:out value="${inverteraa}"/>
```

**OutPut**

[image: outputosgicall]